# Хочу сделать игру в 21 на чисто js и node.js, но не понимаю каким образом можно реализовать это кодом

Tags: javascript

Написать игру 21:

- из meaning и suits собирается колода из 36 карт и пушится в deck
- тасуется(карты в deck перемешиваются рандомно)
- раздается крупье и n-количества участников по 2 карты(количество игроков должно быть именно переменной типо countUsers + 1(1 - это крупье))
- подсчитывается значения карт у игроков и крупье
- если Если сумма значений карт меньше или равно 11, то раздать ещё по одной карте
- сравнить результат крупье и игрока(Если у игрока меньше или равно 21 но больше чем у крупье он выйграл и наоборот)
- вывести победителя
- вывести карты победителя.

Если не сложно то можете объяснить что конкретно как и почему надо делать

Что-то подобное должно быть для составления колоды ↓↓↓

```js
 const suits = [
     {suit:'пики'},
     {suit:'крести'},
     {suit:'черви'},
     {suit:'буби'}
 ];
 const suits = [
     {suit:'пики'},
     {suit:'крести'},
     {suit:'черви'},
     {suit:'буби'}
 ];
const meaning = [
    {mean:'6', value:6},
    {mean:'7', value:7},
    {mean:'8', value:8},
    {mean:'9', value:9},
    {mean:'10', value:10},
    {mean:'11', value:11},
    {mean:'Валет', value:2},
    {mean:'Дама', value:3},
    {mean:'Король', value:4},
    {mean:'Туз', value:11}
]


    let deck = [];
    for (const item of suits) {
        for (const item of meaning) {
            deck.push(description = item.mean + '' + item.suit + '', item.value + '')
        }
    }
    console.log(deck)
```

Comment: ну вот начинай делать игру с тех шагов, которые понимаешь как делать.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий, что конкретно вы не понимаете? Как описать модель, какой язык выбрать, какую выбрать структуру? Опишите вашу проблему конкретнее.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: совсем не обязательно составлять колоду так как у Вас, я знаю что во многих исходниках карточных игр карты нумеруются от 1 до 52 или 1 до 36 как узнать что за карта? проще простого, делим нацело на размер масти например на 9 - это масть,  и берем остаток от деления - это ранг, так же если выводить в консоли игру есть спец ASCII символы для мастей, можно красиво отрисовать игру, я такое делал правда на ++

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно просто алгоритм написать. Крупно он может выглядеть следующим образом:

1. собирается колода из 36 карт - создать массив на 36, разместить в нём карты по порядку (цикл по мастям (масти роли не играют, поэтому просто цикл от 1 до 4) и вложенный цикл по номиналу).
2. тасуется  - создать ещё один массив на 36 и заполнить его случайными числами, потом отсортировать массив с картами по массиву со случайными числами.
3. раздается крупье и n-количества участников по 2 карты - ввести n от пользователя, создать n+1 мерный массив по три карты, заполнить их по две карты, последовательно беря из колоды. Здесь @Инквизитор предлагает удалять, но делать этого не нужно. Для раздачи нужно использовать указатель на верхнюю карту. Перед раздачей ставим указатель (это просто индекс элемента) на первый элемент массива. Раздали карту с указателя, потом сместили указатель на следующий элемент.
4. подсчитывается - пройтись циклом по массиву и посчитать.
5. если набор до 21 меньше половины, то раздать ещё по одной карте - пройтись циклом и добавить по одной карте где надо.
6. подсчитать результат - пройтись циклом по массиву и посчитать и определить выигрышное число очков: у кого больше, но не больше 21. Опять же, @Инквизитор, неудачников удалять не нужно.
7. вывести результаты - вывести на экран.
8. вывести карты с которыми выиграл игрок или крупье - пройтись по массиву, если число очков совпадает с выирышным из п. 6, то вывести на экран.

Comment: 'А теперь мне надо понять как реализовать это кодом) – puhh'. Попросил бы сразу, чтобы тебе код написали, а не учили жить...

Answer (score 1):

Можно, например, сделать так:

---

карта - это объект с такими свойствами:

```
{"name":"валет","suit":"треф","scores":2}
```

колода - это массив таких объектов с 36 элементами:

```
deck = [{card0},{card1},...{card35}]
```

игроки и крупье - объекты, среди свойств которых будет массив выданных карт (изначально нулевой длины). Пусть, например, он называется `hand` ("рука").

нужен служебный массив `players = [player0, player1... playerN]`, где изначально пречислены все игроки плюс крупье.

Делается функция "раздача" (`turn()`), которая может выглядеть так:
из массива `deck` берется рандомная карта и кладется в массив `hand` по очереди каждому игроку/крупье. "Берется" - значит она удаляется из исходного массива `deck`, "кладется" - значит, такая же карта создается в `hand` игрока.

Делается функция "подсчет", которая посчитает сумму очков карт в `hand` и запишет ее в какое-нибудь свойство объекта "игрок".

Ход игры:

Сперва производится цикл начальной раздачи, где для каждого игрока и крупье два раза подряд вызывается функция `turn()`.

Потом в цикле всем им вызывается такое:

- Если игрок есть в массиве `Players`, то для него:

  - вызывается функция "подсчет"
  - сравнение результата подсчета с 11 (половина от 21 с округлением)
  - если очки >= 11, то данный игрок убирается из массива `players`

Этот цикл повторяется до тех пор, пока массив `players` не станет пустым (ну или колода не кончится).

Потом для каждого игрока вывести набранные очки, отобразить карты из его `hand`  и определить выигравшего (того, кто набрал максимально близко к 21, у кого перебор - проиграл по-любому). Это даже описывать смысла нет.

---

Интересные факты:

- мастей "крести" и "буби" в природе не существует.
- Карты с номиналом "11" тоже не существует. Только туз.
- Валет, дама и король имеют достоинство в 2, 3 и 4 очка, а не 8/9/10.

Comment: Дело в том что нужен другой подход. Если  допустим нужна будет колода из 72 карт, но нужно будет дописать в 2 массив несколько значений и всё + если делать так то в теории можно немного изменить функцию и сделать выбор колоды 72 или 36 карт + количество игроков должно быть аргументом, а не значениями массива.

Comment: Поэтому я не могу реализовать код. Если делать так то в теории оно будет работать, но это костыль.

Comment: + колода карт должна быть массивом и значения  после пуша карт должны будут перемешаться, а потом поочерёдно должны пушиться карты крупье и игрокам.

Comment: 1) колода у меня и так массив. 2) колоду и игроков можно банально генерировать по заданным исходным данным - хоть 131 игроков с  колодой в 1347 карт. 3) если представлять карту и игрока как объект, в них можно записывать (заранее или в процессе генерации) любые другие свойства, например, css-классы - потом скриптом будет легче легкого формировать лейаут страницы, ибо удобнее дергать нужные свойства.

ИМХО.

Comment: А  теперь мне надо понять как реализовать это кодом)

Comment: Можешь примерно показать как это должно выглядеть? Очень нуждаюсь. Я так и не смог нормально реализовать колоду, крупье и игроков с раздачей  карт(((